# How to define a subdag taks in Airflow from another dag.py file?

Tags: airflow

I want to make a parent DAG with a few child DAGs that get called via the `SubDagOperator`.

- I can only find examples how to dynamically create Subdags in the SubDagOperator task.
- However, in this case I want standalone child DAGs that are already defined in a DAG.py file and stitch those together in a parent dag

If I set the SubDAGOperator task with just the Dag Name of the child dag:

```
task_1 = SubDagOperator(
    task_id="task_1",
    subdag=child_dag_name,
    dag=parent_dag
)
```

I get the following Error:

```
NameError: name 'child_dag_name' is not defined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wiring top-level DAGs together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325525/wiring-top-level-dags-together)

Comment: I already found this question. As according to your full answer here, there seems no quick and easy solution, so I might as well try the TriggerDagRunOperator option. This seems more scalable anyway. I want to trigger my first dag once, and then the second dag needs to be triggered once if all tasks of previous one succeed exactly 24h later. Is this possible with TriggerDagRunOperator?

Answer (score 0):

*This answer equally relies on knowledge of Python as much it does on having know-how of Airflow*

Recall that

- `python`: `import`ing a module means that all top-level (indentation zero) stuff is immediately executed (during import process)
- `airflow`: only those `DAG` *objects* are picked by `scheduler` / `webserver` that are occur on top-level (indentation zero) of dag-definition file

---

Keeping above 2 things in mind, here's what you can do

- create a *helper / utility function* in your `child_dag.py` file to insantiate and return a `DAG` object for child-dag
- use that helper function for instantiating the top-level child-DAG as well as for creating `SubDagOperator` task

---

**dag_object_builder.py**

```
from typing import Dict, Any

from airflow.models import DAG


def create_dag_object(dag_id: str, dag_params: Dict[str, Any]) -> DAG:
    dag: DAG = DAG(dag_id=dag_id, **dag_params)
    return dag
```

**child_dag.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Dict, Any

from airflow.models import DAG

from src.main.subdag_example import dag_object_builder

default_args: Dict[str, Any] = {
    "owner": "my_owner",
    "email": ["my_username@my_domain.com"],
    "weight_rule": "downstream",
    "retries": 1
}

...


def create_child_dag_object(dag_id: str) -> DAG:
    my_dag: DAG = dag_object_builder.create_dag_object(
        dag_id=dag_id,
        dag_params={
            "start_date": datetime(year=2019, month=7, day=10, hour=21, minute=30),
            "schedule_interval": None,
            "max_active_runs": 1,
            "default_view": "graph",
            "catchup": False,
            "default_args": default_args
        }
    )
    return my_dag


my_child_dag: DAG = create_child_dag_object(dag_id="my_child_dag")
```

**parent_dag.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Dict, Any

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator

from src.main.subdag_example import child_dag
from src.main.subdag_example import dag_object_builder

default_args: Dict[str, Any] = {
    "owner": "my_owner",
    "email": ["my_username@my_domain.com"],
    "weight_rule": "downstream",
    "retries": 1
}

my_parent_dag: DAG = dag_object_builder.create_dag_object(
    dag_id="my_parent_dag",
    dag_params={
        "start_date": datetime(year=2019, month=7, day=10, hour=21, minute=30),
        "schedule_interval": None,
        "max_active_runs": 1,
        "default_view": "graph",
        "catchup": False,
        "default_args": default_args
    }
)

...

my_subdag_task: SubDagOperator = SubDagOperator(
    task_id="my_subdag_task",
    dag=my_parent_dag,
    subdag=child_dag.create_child_dag_object(dag_id="my_subdag")
)
```

---

- If your intention is to link-up DAGs together and you don't have any particular requirement that necessitates using a `SubDagOperator`, then I would suggest using the `TriggerDagRunOperator` instead since `SubDag`s have their [share of nuisances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51301763/3679900).
- Read more about it here: [Wiring top-level DAGs together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51325525/3679900)